# Rollback everything if method within transaction fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a set of inserts and updates that all need to be rolled back if any of them fail. A good portion of these updates and inserts are abstracted out so they can be reused. When I start a transaction, then call the method to kick off the abstracted inserts, the failure isn't sent up to the original transaction block - it just commits everything before that method

```
    def decline_check
        Check.transaction do
            # Set default updates, then a voided date if the check has already been printed.
            check_attributes = {:status => 'Voided', :status_date => Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}
            check_attributes[:voided_date] = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if check.status == "Printed"

            # Update check status
            check.update_attributes!(check_attributes)

            decline(current_user)
        end
    end

private

    def decline current_user
        # execute some insert  here that fails
    end
```

How can I get the a rollback in `decline` to trigger a rollback in `decline_check`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` if you want to manually trigger a transaction rollback.

A better design would be to try and find a way to validate before doing your database interaction.

Your comment in `decline current_user` says that the insert is going to fail. If you're refering to a database level failure it should automatically trigger the rollback.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Placing that manual raise in there worked as expected - my issue was higher up which was incorrectly displaying a "failed" message. Thanks.